# Detect if Address Bar is Showing in iOS

Tags: javascript, ipad, ios

On a webpage viewed on an iOS device I would like to use JavaScript to detect if the address bar is currently showing. Or if I could detect if the page was launched from the home screen or not.

The main goal I have is to add instructions how to add to the home screen if they didn't launch the page from there then hide the instructions otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer you can check against "window.navigator.standalone" for iOS to see if the user has the app loaded in full screen mode.

More info [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1950-Detecting-iPhone-s-App-Mode-Full-Screen-Mode-For-Web-Applications.htm).